# Round number but keep exact digits

Tags: vb.net, formatting, significant-digits

when I call this function like this Rounded(50.080, 3) Im getting "50.08" how can I force to keep the trailing zeros?

```
Public Function Rounded(ByVal Number, ByVal Decimals)
    Rounded = Int(Number * 10 ^ Decimals + 1 / 2) / 10 ^ Decimals
End Function
```

Comment: You mean the trailing zero?

Comment: Don't you mean trailing zeroes? That is a presentation issue which really shouldn't be the concern of a rounding function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim RoundedString As String = FormatNumber(Rounded, Decimals, , , TriState.False)
```

should do it for you

Comment: this is not working because its converting "1542.800" into "1,542.800"

Answer (score 1):

Please, for your own health, turn `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` on, stop using the return variable unless you really want to, and drop the legacy VB6 functions (like `Int`).

Then you can probably hack something together with a string format like this:

```
Public Function Rounded(number As Decimal, decimals As Integer) As String
    Return number.ToString("0." & New String("0"c, decimals))
End Function
```

It’s generally better to just use the format string yourself if you can, though, as in `num.ToString("0.000")` for three decimal places, and drop `Rounded` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decimal.Round(Value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`,
see more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s0xa85y.aspx)